# OpenBSD - How to manage users that can be SSH into?

Tags: openssh, openbsd

**Question**: How do I disable/enable which users can be connected to via SSH?

Can all users be connected into SSH by default or do I need to enable it for the user first?

Answer (score 1):

The SSH service is enabled by default on OpenBSD (unless you answered "no" to the question `Start sshd(8) by default?` during the installation).

If a user has an account on the system, the SSH service will let them log in with their password. When they add their public SSH key to their `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file, they will be able to log in using their SSH key, like on any other system running SSH.

The configuration of the service is available in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` it has helpful comments in it, but you should also read the [`sshd_config(8)`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config) manual.

To disallow two specific users from logging in using SSH, you may use e.g.

```
DenyUsers bob alan
```

See the [`DenyUsers` section](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#DenyUsers) in the `sshd_config(8)` manual.  You may also want to look at `AllowUsers`, `DenyGroups` and `AllowGroups`.

This is not different from doing the same thing on Linux or any other Unix running OpenSSH.

If you make changes to the SSH server configuration, you need to restart the SSH service.  You do this by rebooting or by telling the `sshd` daemon to re-read the configuration through the command

```
rcctl reload sshd
```

(as root).